# Is it possible to deduce the function return type from the parameter function?

Tags: generics, zig

For educational reasons i'm trying to create the simple `Option` type in zig. This is my attempt, and it seems to work correctly:

```
fn Opt(comptime T: type) type {
    return union(enum) {
        some: T,
        none: void,

        pub fn of(x: T) Opt(T) {
            return .{ .some = x };
        }

        pub fn map(self: @This(), comptime R: type, comptime mapFn: fn (x: T) R) Opt(R) {
            return switch (self) {
                .none => .none,
                .some => Opt(R).of(mapFn(self.some)),
            };
        }
    };
}
```

So, the `map` takes the function and returns the `Opt(R)`, which in turn has the `mapFn` return type. What bothers me, is that you have to explicitly pass the `R` type to `map`:

```
const opt: Opt(i32) = Opt(i32).of(101);

const newOpt = opt.map(f32, struct {
    fn f(x: i32) f32 {
        return 1.0 + @intToFloat(f32, x);
    }
}.f);
```

My question is: can i avoid passing type (`f32`) in `opt.map(f32,...` call?
Looks like it should be possible to deduce it from the `mapFn` return type.

Is it even possible in zig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible as long as the function is not generic (eg has 'anytype' as an arg).

```
pub fn map(self: @This(), comptime mapFn: anytype) Opt(@typeInfo(@TypeOf(mapFn)).Fn.return_type.?) {
    const R = @typeInfo(@TypeOf(mapFn)).Fn.return_type.?;
    …
```

Unfortunately, doing this makes errors and editor support worse and it can be harder to understand the type of the function

Comment: Wow that's cool. A bit ugly though. And unidiomatic also, right?

Comment: Is there any reference on idiomatic zig style? Should i mostly follow the `c` idioms?

Comment: When stdlib functions do stuff like this, they generally have a seperate function for getting the return value. like fn MapReturnValue(...args) to organize a bit better. You can look at some functions in std/math.zig and std/meta.zig and likely other places for examples of how the stdlib uses computed return types